# Prestashop name validation and repair

Tags: validation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have problem with my own csv importer in prestashop 1.6. When my product name look like this: `2=1 2 battery& 1 pilot )`

Presta validation get my error like this: `Property Product->name is not valid`

Do you know, how I must convert the name that presta validation don't get me error ?

My code view like this:

```
$object                     = new Product();
$object->price              = number_format($data[$row_header['recommended_selling_price']] * $rate, 2,".","");
$object->id_tax_rules_group = $taxID;

$languages=Language::getLanguages();
foreach($languages as $lang){
    $object->name[$lang['id_lang']]=$namecache;
    $object->link_rewrite[$lang['id_lang']]= $this->slugify($namecache);
    $object->description[$lang['id_lang']]=$data[$row_header['detailed_full_text_en']];
    $object->description_short[$lang['id_lang']]=substr($data[$row_header['full_text_EN']], 0, 800);
}
```

Comment: Try to var_dump Validate::isCatalogName($namecache) and tell us the result. At least you can change invalid characters and then after import you FIND & REPLACE those Characters

Comment: I use str_replace for = and & syntax and now all its works. Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you might solve the problem by escaping or converting the string like this :

```
$object->name[$lang['id_lang']] = utf8_encode($namecache);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work well enough. In my file there are German characters and after using this function they are replaced with some weird ones.